# JQuery .height() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a calendar website. In this I have a calendar div in which the calendar loads, wrapped inside a content div. **In this header and footer are of fixed position. The calendar loads in the blue part.**

[image]

### HTML

```
<div class ="content">
   <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.content{
   background: #fcfcfc;
   height: 100%;
   margin: -70px 0 -20px;
   padding: 70px 0 20px;
}

#calendar{
   background: #fcfcfc;
   margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   border: 1px solid #888;

}
```

### JS

```
var calHeight = $(".content").height();
```

**From the image I think calHeight should give something around 390 but its giving 594 in chrome and 565 in firefox.**.

What should I do to get calHeight the displayed size?

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using jQuery.outerHeight().

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

It returns the height including Margin and Padding.

Answer (score 0):

your var is named calHeight, so you want the height of the calendar div?
You are using the content class to measure the height not the calendar!

```
var calHeight = $("#calendar").height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qwk6x/40/)**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').children().height($(window).height());
});
```